# How to get instance of SessionFactoryImplementor?

Tags: hibernate

As in title: how can I get the instance of `SessionFactoryImplementor`? What I hacked in the code is:

```
SessionFactoryImplementator  sfi
    = (SessionFactoryImplementator) session.getSessionFactory();
```

I don't like it too much and I was wondering if there is any other, more elegant way of acquiring the instance of implementator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't find any public class that returns the implementor, so your approach is fine. (For example [look here](http://www.jdocs.com/hibernate/3.1.3/org/hibernate/engine/SessionFactoryImplementor.html), under usage > returned by)

Comment: Yeah. It seems the only way to me as well. I don't like it, but what can I do? ;)

Comment: Example link broken

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
SessionFactoryImplementor sfi = (SessionFactoryImplementor) ctx.getBean("sessionFactory");
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as in question but described as "I don't like it too much".

Answer (score 1):

After reading the above comments, I would propose that the original author's code example...
`SessionFactoryImplementator  sfi = (SessionFactoryImplementator) session.getSessionFactory();`
and then the latter re-coding of the same principal:
`SessionFactoryImplementor sfi = (SessionFactoryImplementor) ctx.getBean("sessionFactory");`
Anyone who is in fact using Spring should ALWAYS defer to the latter approach as there is no way of knowing how Spring3/4's SessionFactoryBean might choose to re-implement "openSession" etc. (or the developer application), but point being that accessing it through a Spring ApplicationContext ensures that you have the "highest-level" wrapped version of the actual SessionFactory, which should implement the greatest number of Hibernate SessionFactory-related interfaces (whether wrapped through AoP or compile-time class-weaving, etc.)

If you know that there is only one Hibernate SessionFactory in your "appCtx", then an even better way would be:
`appCtx.getBean(org.hibernate.SessionFactory.class);`